# How to filter after following filter in knex

Tags: sql, filter, knex.js

As example my database holding 10 group of data. I have 4 group data category_slug is **stationery-stamp-ink**

I doing filter in knex.

```
.where("category_slug","stationery-stamp-ink")
.orWhereIn("type.name", "Sticky Notes")
```

As top query return some data holding "Sticky Notes" without "stationery-stamp-ink".

I expected, all data holding **stationery-stamp-ink** who has Sticky Notes.

```
// third data category_slug don't match the stationery-stamp-ink

[
  {
    "product_name": "PENCO Steel Clip S - Ivory / Navy",
    "category_name": "Stationery / Stamp Ink",
    "category_slug": "stationery-stamp-ink",
    "type_name": "Stationery"
  },
  {
    "product_name": "Sarasa Clip Gel Pen 0.5 (20 Colors)",
    "category_name": "Stationery / Stamp Ink",
    "category_slug": "stationery-stamp-ink",
    "type_name": "Stationery"
  },
  {
    "product_name": "Trolls Paper Mini Stickers Set (10 designs)",
    "category_name": "Notes / Paper",
    "category_slug": "notes-paper",
    "type_name": "Sticky Notes"
  },
  {
    "product_name": "Mini Tassel",
    "category_name": "Stationery / Stamp Ink",
    "category_slug": "stationery-stamp-ink",
    "type_name": "Sticky Notes"
  },
  {
    "product_name": "Mildliner BRUSH PEN Double Ended - Warm",
    "category_name": "Stationery / Stamp Ink",
    "category_slug": "stationery-stamp-ink",
    "type_name": null
  }
]
```

Comment: I supposed that  `type.name` in `orWhereIn("type.name", "Sticky Notes")` is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter only rows that has `Sticky Notes` **and** `stationery-stamp-ink` then you need to do:

```
.where("category_slug","stationery-stamp-ink")
.where("type_name", "Sticky Notes")
```

instead of OR.